# Excel validation number from specific characters

Tags: excel, validation, binary

i have a problem with excel, i need to create validation that let enter a number with a characters 1 and 0, it can be 011 101 011100 110101 and etc..I just need to check is it binary number, and if its not then to get error..any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this formula for validation:

if your data couldn't contain spaces:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"1",""),"0","")=""
```

if your data could contain spaces:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"1",""),"0",""))=""
```

Comment: am tried this IF(B6="Dvejetainė";SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B6,"1",""),"0","")="";)
but seems it dont work

Comment: try to use `IF(B6="Dvejetainė";SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B6;"1";"");"0";"")="";)` (change `,` to `;` in formula)

Comment: But I can't understand your formula: if `B6="Dvejetainė"` is true, you trying to detect whether `B6` is binary? How it is possible?

Comment: i dont know is it possible, am just trying to get how to do it :D am checking if B6 is true and then its true, i want to check is it binary

Comment: does it help to change `,` to `;` in formula (see my comment above)?

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack would be to use BIN2DEC in another column. If the original cell contained a valid binary number the formula will return a decimal number, if not it will return an error for which you can check e.g. with ISERROR.

Edit: a nested use of ISERROR and BIN2DEC should also work as a validation.

Comment: Can you explain me more with functions ISERROR/IFERROR? i tried but dont work with my validation/error message

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem was my translation of the function names from my locale into English, but ISERROR(BIN2DEC()) returns either TRUE or FALSE for me.